# Generating PHP server stubs with thrift

Tags: php, thrift

So yesterday i wrote my own thrift IDL which went fine and now I'm trying to generate some code from it
With that in mind I went to generate code in PHP, Java, C# and Python with my first written IDL
So on thrift 0.10.0 I used this command:

```
thrift --gen py:new_styles --gen csharp:async --gen java --gen php:server thriftfile.thrift
```

This gave me what I wanted for all the languages except for PHP because I want to generate some server stubs but it won't let me
It only creates my Service1.php, Service2.php, Types.php in the namespace I defined in the IDL

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We love errors, they tell us so much. Do you have any errors for us? Warnings will do too.

Comment: @Havenard I didn't have any errors but I proceeded as followed, I took the sample php server file from the apache thrift site. After misunderstanding the usage of thrift in its whole
But now I have a server hosting the files and a python client being stuck on EOF errors that I might post in a moment if I really can't figure it out